# Для чего нужен github?

Tags: github

Имею опыт с системами контроля версий, гитхаб нужен для совместной разработки чего-либо. Но откуда такая популярность, какой профит от этого? Очень много кто этим пользуется, какие возможности я упускаю? Буду очень благодарен, тем, кто поможет разобраться.

Comment: А сами пробовали разобраться?

> какой профит от этого?

Например, почитать [прейскурант](https://github.com/plans).

Comment: Я имел ввиду какой профит тем, кто пишет код.

Comment: ...А еще гитхаб можно использовать как хостинг для статики. [Блога](http://neoascetic.github.com/), например :)

Comment: Для хранения исходных кодов программы

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Github стал популярен за счет того, что имел обширные возможности для социального взаимодействия, фактически — социальная сеть для разработки open source приложений. Там действительно очень удобный инструментарий для правки open source проектов — форкнулся, сделал изменения, сделал pull-request и твой коммит уже в основной ветке.

Ну а также мощный и бесплатный инструментарий all-in-one для разработки — git как VCS, вики, issue-трекер. Ну вот по этой уже были аналоги — тот же Google Code.

Comment: почему это популярно, работать над опенсорс проектами?

Comment: Тут есть пару вариантов:
1) потому что можешь заглянуть внутрь как что работает. Для многих код - лучшая документация
2) потому что можно расширить нужную библиотеку, не начиная все с нуля
3) потому при использовании опен-сорса сильно экономится время на разработку.
4) этим можно блеснуть в резюме. В стартапах на активность в гитхабе обращают внимание. +сразу видно какой код человек пишет
5) просто научиться чему-то новому. Технологии или фреймворку, если на работе нету времени на это
6) похвастаться миру, что ты написал вот такой зашибенный фреймворк

Comment: правильно ли я тогда понимаю, что главное это поункты:
4, так как это чистый профит
5, аналогично, знания и технологии == деньги
6, потешить самолюбие, кто это не любит?)

верно? спрашиваю, потому как ни разу не было проблем с документацией, расширением библиотеки, не имею представления насколько часто такие нужды встречаются у остальных

Comment: @FrenchCheese, IMHO главное это пункты 1, 3 и 5. 

С 2) можно спорить из-за проблем с переносом и поддержкой (отслеживать чужие правки хочешь - не хочешь, а придется). Лучше подобную функциональность вытаскивать в статику, в крайнем случае в динамически подгружаемую приложением библиотеку.

Comment: Есть ли какие нибудь советы, как лучше найти проект, в котором можно принести пользу, имея скромный опыт?

Comment: Мой совет будет таким: определиться с языком программирования. Найти шумные проекты по этому языку (java - junit, jenkins, Spring, сотни их; C++ - Qt, Linux, notepad++; и т.д..) с помощью гугла или напрямую с github/codeproject.
Важно обратить внимание на: есть ли багтрекер и незакрытые таски в проекте, не мертвый ли проект(когда был последний коммит), комьюнити вокруг проекта(форум, кому задавать вопросы, наличие документации и вики)